# how can I mark for first value on every groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like behind

```
      A      B  
0     0      0   
1     0      0 
2     0      0 
3     1      0 
4     0      0 
5     0      0
6     0      0
7     0      1  
8     1      1  
9     1      1  
10    0      1 
11    0      1 
12    0      1  
13    1      1
14    0      2  
15    0      2    
16    0      2 
17    1      2  
18    0      2 
19    1      2
20    1      2
```

and I want to make 'C' which is a marker for the first value of A for every group 'B'

```
      A      B      C
0     0      0      0
1     0      0      0
2     0      0      0
3     1      0      1
4     0      0      0
5     0      0      0
6     0      0      0
7     0      1      0
8     1      1      1
9     1      1      0
10    0      1      0
11    0      1      0
12    0      1      0
13    1      1      0
14    0      2      0
15    0      2      0
16    0      2      0
17    1      2      1
18    0      2      0
19    1      2      0
20    1      2      0
```

I have no idea to do this
I tried the groupby method but I failed to put them in a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `groupby` is not necessary, because is possible test duplicated values per multiple columns with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and create new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['A','B']), 0, df['A'])
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   0  0  0
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  0
3   1  0  1
4   0  0  0
5   0  0  0
6   0  0  0
7   0  1  0
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  1  0
11  0  1  0
12  0  1  0
13  1  1  0
14  0  2  0
15  0  2  0
16  0  2  0
17  1  2  1
18  0  2  0
19  1  2  0
20  1  2  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` and `transform` and `np.where`:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x.duplicated(), 0, x))
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
    A  B  C
0   0  0  0
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  0
3   1  0  1
4   0  0  0
5   0  0  0
6   0  0  0
7   0  1  0
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  1  0
11  0  1  0
12  0  1  0
13  1  1  0
14  0  2  0
15  0  2  0
16  0  2  0
17  1  2  1
18  0  2  0
19  1  2  0
20  1  2  0
```